# wireshark generic dissector- using the packet sequence to define the message

Tags: wireshark, custom-protocol, wireshark-dissector

I am not sure if stackoverflow is the right place to put this question, but it seems like.

I am trying to write a dissector using the generic dissector plugin (http://wsgd.free.fr/). I have a small protocol that uses the first packet of a connection to send some config and the rest to send data. So I need to write a dissector that is able to interpret the packet according to the sequence number.

I have read the documentation but the use of functions is still not clear to me. has anyone that has created a dissector using this tool give me a tip?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you resolved your issue? It looks like wsgd is not helpful writting protocol dissectors depending on meta-information (message sequence, stateful protocols), you should probably use [Lua](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Lua) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Global Data in wsgd dissector.

Declare it in headaer file with:

```
GLOBAL_DATA_TYPE      T_global_data
```

The whole example is here: http://wsgd.free.fr/wsgd_format_GLOBAL_DATA_more_info.txt.